# How to get the chunk times from pydub split_on_silence?

Tags: python, pydub

I'm using `split_on_silence` to split a mp3 file to multiple segments:

```
sound        = AudioSegment.from_mp3(TEST_FILE)
audio_chunks = split_on_silence(sound, min_silence_len=300, keep_silence=50, silence_thresh=-40 )
```

Is it possible (How can I do it) to get the origin start-stop times for each chunk?

Comment: I've found this function here `https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/pull/442` with an option `with_timing` but honestly couldn't make it work.

Comment: How did you end up dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little change to the code of `split_on_silence` function:

```
for range_i, range_ii in pairwise(output_ranges):
        print(">>", timestamp(range_i[0]/1000), timestamp(range_i[1]/1000))
        last_end = range_i[1]
        next_start = range_ii[0]
        if next_start < last_end:
            range_i[1] = (last_end+next_start)//2
            range_ii[0] = range_i[1]
```

Just add print line or make anything with those variable of `range_i` which is seemingly the time of those crops. Didn't test the precision but it seem to be ok. This function is `/pydub/silence.py` in your installation place.

Timestamp is just:

```
def timestamp(mseconds):
    (hours, mseconds) = divmod(mseconds, 3600)
    (minutes, mseconds) = divmod(mseconds, 60)
    return f"{hours:02.0f}:{minutes:02.0f}:{mseconds:06.3f}"
```

used with `datetime` library to be more exact.